# SQL Server: how to select double cities from database

Tags: sql-server

I have an amazing problem on a 3 million rows database.

The database stores all cities in the world but there are doubles:

[image]

I would like to `SELECT` all rows which has the same Latitude and Longitude.
How to select the whole row, not just Latitude and Longitude?

I would like to list the results like this:

[image]

What I **don't want to list** the results like this:

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (PARTITION BY latitude, Longitude 
ORDER BY latitude, Longitude) AS RN
FROM World
```

[image]

Comment: in short you just want to get the entries with duplicates? if that's correct then use EXISTS based on long and lat

Comment: check my answer

Comment: my answer gives correct output can you check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select country, city, accentcity, region, population, region, population, latitude, longitude
from (
      select country
            ,city
            ,accentcity
            ,region
            ,population
            ,latitude
            ,longitude
            ,count(*) over(partition by latitude, longitude) as dup
      from world
     ) as Temp
where dup > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT Latitude,Longitude,COUNT(Latitude) As NumOfRec
FROM World
GROUP BY Latitude,Longitude
)

SELECT w.* FROM WORLD w 
JOIN CTE c ON w.Latitude=c.Latitude AND w.Longitude=c.Longitude
WHERE c.NumOfRec>1;
```

Comment: Thank you but I would like to list row by row and I will decide what to delete

Comment: can you please elaborate further? did you tried this code?

Comment: got it. but I guess you got your answer, right? if not then change select * to select w.* and rest is all fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this will help you,

```
 select * from World where exists( 
        select * from
            (
            select WorldLatCount = Count(*) 
            from World as WorldLat where World.Longitutde = WorldLat.Longitutde and WorldLat.Latitude = World.Latitude
        ) 
     as WorldCounts where WorldCounts.WorldLatCount> 1

   )
```

you will get result like this

```
Country Longitutde  Latitude
ad  42.30   45.50
ad  42.30   45.50
ef  42.78   45.59
ef  42.78   45.59
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by longitude and latitude and city, use having > 1, and use the result as subquery to filter correct rows from the table.

```sql
Select * from world 
 where city IN 
      (Select City From World Group by longitude, latitude, city                        
      having count(* ) > 1 )
```