# SQL: delete duplicate rows with clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with all the cities in the world.

and if I run [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320377/sql-server-how-to-select-double-cities-from-database/44320521?noredirect=1#comment75646681_44320521) query I can see there are doubles:

[image]

I already used this query to delete all duplicate rows:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (PARTITION BY Country, City, AccentCity, Region, Population, latitude, Longitude 
ORDER BY Country, City, AccentCity, Region, Population, latitude, Longitude) AS RN
FROM ExperimentWorld
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN<>1
```

I would now run it again and delete all columns where `latitude` and `Longitude` are the same and if two rows are the same like in the picture above I want to keep the one where `population` has some value and delete the one with `population` '0'

Comment: Add a where clause. Delete from cte where ... population < 1 and....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query --

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY Country
            ,City
            ,AccentCity
            ,Region
            ,Population
            ,latitude
            ,Longitude ORDER BY Population DESC
            ) AS RowNum
    FROM ExperimentWorld
    )
DELETE
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum > 1
```

Comment: Yes it worked, I had edit and select just 'latitude,Longitude'